# how to do nested queries in supabase for m2m relations

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-flutter

i have this structure in my database in supabase :

```
create table categories (
  "id" serial primary key,
  "name" text
);

create table jobs (
  "id" serial primary key,
  "job_title" text,
);

create table job_cat_rel (
  "job" int references jobs,
  "cat" int references categories,
  primary key (job, cat)
);
```

based on [These docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/joins-and-nesting?output-format=table&language=dart) from `supabase` I should simply call it in dart like this :

```
final data = await supabase.from('jobs').select('id, job_title, categories(id, name)');
```

but running this gives me a 400 error .. any help with that?

Comment: final data = await supabase
    .from('jobs')
    .select('id, job_title, job_cat_rel!inner(cat(id, name))')
    .execute();
your query should look like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use `!inner()` join to retrieve nested values.

So you'll have something like this:

```
final data = await supabase.from('jobs').select('id, job_title, categories:categories!inner(id, name)');
```